# Passing value from InAppBrowser to index.html

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, cordova

I am creating an Phonegap App for that i am using an inAppBrowser.

Now my requirement is that i need to pass a value from inAppBrowser and store it in  index.html page variable ?? how can i do that

My code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
  <head>
  <title>First App</title>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

  function onLoad() 
    { 
       document.addEventListener("deviceready",lrInit,true); 
       var iabRef = null;

    }

   function lrInit()
   {
       //var lrtoken=window.localStorage.getItem('lrtoken');
       var globalToken = null;
       iabRef=window.open('some_url','_blank','location=yes');
       iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { });
       iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) 
       { 
        var url=event.url;
        if((url.search("token"))>0)
            {
               var k=url.search("token");

                //I need to store this "token" variable into "globalToken" variable declared 
               token=url.substring(k+6,k+42);

               //window.localStorage.setItem('lrtoken',token);

               //alert("Token=" + token);
               iabRef.close();
             }



        });
       iabRef.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) { alert('error: ' + event.message); });
       iabRef.addEventListener('exit', function(event) {});


     }

 </script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="submit" value="Facebook" onclick="lrInit();">

<div id="profile"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

//Sorry about any paranthesis missing issues.

Comment: Does `localStorage.token= token;` won't work? It should work just fine.

Comment: thanks JunM..now its working..idk why sessionStorage was not working earlier.

Comment: does not work in android...since the main webviews localstorage is separate from the inappbrowser instance localstorage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use LocalStorage to solve this, or you may use an external service to do that like [parse](https://www.parse.com/?gclid=CIqnpb2avLsCFQhZ3god8wUAng) as example to save your data inside InAppBrowser then read it again in your app